# How to sync client for inbox and calendar resource of a user

Tags: calendar, icalendar, webdav, caldav

- I am trying to understand event scheduling with Caldav
- I use CalendarServer
- Using mac iCal Client, 'userA' created an event and invited 'userB'
- At this point 'userB' has two items for the same event in his collections:

  - Inbox - Request from 'userA'  ------------- /userB/inbox/123456789.ics
  - Calendar - Server created for user ---------/userB/calendar/987654321.ics

They both refer to same event.

For the userB client, I need access to both the items at the same time:

```
   * To Delete from 'Inbox' when userB "Accepts"
   * To update 'Calendar' when userB "Accepts"
```

Right now I send two different requests to `'inbox' endpoint` and `'calendar' endpoint` which leads to sync issues on the client side

How can I access both the .ics files for userB in a single request to Caldav server??

Please provide pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, there is no RFC'ed standard way to delete the Inbox item and update the calendar resource in a single HTTP request in DAV.

There is an Apple extension to do bulk changes: [Calendar Server Bulk Change Requests for *DAV Protocols](https://github.com/evert/calendarserver-extensions/blob/master/calendarserver-bulk-change.txt). But I wouldn't use it for this particular issue.

The iTIP resource in the Inbox of an auto-scheduling CalDAV server plays no functional part in the scheduling. Consider it a notification. Hence it doesn't actually lead to synchronization issues.
It's up to the client (auto-scheduling or not) to figure out whether an Inbox item is still valid and needs to be displayed (or can be deleted). Eg if the event resource is valid, there is no point in showing a 'needs-action' iTIP notification.

You can also look at the [SEQUENCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.7.4) property, though it is probably a better idea to compare the iTIP to the actual event.